Is there a way to download sheets from Autodesk using its API?
I am currently working on a data integration project involving Autodesk, and I need to download PDF versions of sheets. However, I have been unable to locate an endpoint in the Sheets API that facilitates this.
There is an API for getting the sheets' details but I cannot find any endpoint to download sheets in PDF format. Is there any way to download them using the API?

Yes, there is some updates that will help you download the 'vector PDF' (not the old-leaflet-png-based PDF), directly through APIs.
Not exactly 'official', but via the derivative APIs:

Here is a blog post that details the process:
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/download-your-revit-2d-views-pdfs

You can try this yourself, by trying the demo app: https://aps-revit-pdf-exporter.autodesk.io/

The feature was announced here:
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/advanced-option-rvtdwg-2d-views-svf2-post-job


Restrictions:
Specifically, your Revit file needs to be:
1. from version 2022 or later
2. published on APS after November 4th of 2021
3. For the demo, check for your browser pop-up blocker, when it tries to download the PDF

Hope that helps,
Michael
